# How to get name and creation date of all files in a folder in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, jailbreak

I am using the following code to get creation date of a file at a given path and it works fine.

```
NSDictionary* attrs = [fm attributesOfItemAtPath:@"/Users/me/Desktop/ios" error:nil];

    if (attrs != nil) {
        NSDate *date = (NSDate*)[attrs objectForKey: NSFileCreationDate];
        NSLog(@"Date Created: %@", [date description]);

    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Not found");
    }
```

Now I want to get the names and creation dates of all files in a folder given at a path.How can I do that? Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first get list of all files from your directory & then loop until all file completes

```
NSString *bundleRoot = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *dirContents = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:bundleRoot error:nil];
for(int i=0;i<[dirContents count];i++)
{
NSDictionary* attrs = [fm attributesOfItemAtPath:[dirContents objectAtIndex:i] error:nil];

    if (attrs != nil) {
        NSDate *date = (NSDate*)[attrs objectForKey: NSFileCreationDate];
        NSLog(@"Date Created: %@", [date description]);

    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Not found");
    }
}
```

Comment: And recurse to get contents of sub-directories?